# Saying "You and I might be happy together" as an answer to the question "Why do you want to date me?"

Tags: word-usage

Let's say a guy asked a girl out, and the girl said "Why do you want to date me?".
In that case to mean that it is possible that they are going to be happy together in the future, the guy can say **"You and I can be happy together."**. What about **"You and I might be happy together."** I know that we can use **"might"** to refer to a future possibility, but somehow in the sentence and context I gave, it sounds somewhat unnatural to me. Does it sound unnatural to you as well, or is it ok to say **"You and I might be happy together"** to mean it is possible that they're going to be happy together in the future?

*Note*: I know that "might" indicates a lower possibility than "can".

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the **can** sentence sounds a little formulaic. I would use **might** or **could**, but the key is the tone you use when saying it. If you seem uncomfortable, then **might** will sound like you have doubt, and that's not very attractive. But if you don't sound too serious when you say it, it sounds more like optimism for a good relationship.

Comment: I would be more inclined to say "because you are attractive and interesting" and leave the "might/can be happy together" stuff for much later. If I were the girl, I'd run a mile from a guy who said that before a first date.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So they're both okay. @MichaelHarvey Okay, I appreciate your opinion. :) I just made up a context.